# SQL calculate total price

Tags: sql

new here (plus sorry for the bad english..), and I have some SQL difficulties with two tables here - Sells and Product:

```
Product:

ProductID | Product | Price
____________________________
1         | walnuts | 16
2         | cashew  | 25
3         | peanuts | 4

Sells (each product kilograms sold):

Day | walnuts | cashew | hazelnut
__________________________________
1   | 2       | 3      | 1
2   | 8       | 6      | 25
3   | 1       | 3      | 12
```

What I want to display is the total money earned in day 2 (for example) so how can i calculate that?

Comment: You should change your table design. Don't use values are column names

Comment: If this is SQL Server you can use the `UNPIVOT` clause to make this easy, but in any case you probably don't want values as column names.

Comment: Yea.. I guess, but I'm stuck right now :/ any suggestion?

Comment: First question.  Which dbms are you using?????  That's the most important information.  The syntax may vary between dbms.

Comment: Since you are just starting, I suggest you change your table design.  There are only 3 records on each table and you can't solve it.  Imagine when there are millions records.

Comment: As multiple people mentioned, change your design. Have 2 columns in Sells, Day and ProductID. Reference ProductID to the Product table. Now your future queries (including this one) are much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way of designing table is not good.

```
**Item table:**

    product_id | product_name | price
    __________________________________
    1          | Some1        | 20
    2          | Some2        | 30
    3          | Some3        | 40

    **sale table :**

    sale_id  |  product_id | quantity 
    __________________________________
    1        | 2           | 2
    2        | 1           | 1
    3        | 3           | 2
```

Now apply query:

```
SELECT sale.quantity*item.price as TOTAL FROM item,sale WHERE item.product_id=sale.product_id;
```

if you have more columns, then you can apply more filters.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Change your table structure**

Your db table structure is not good.
Using the product variety as a column is not the way. Rather use following structure:

```
Product:

ProductID | Product | Price
____________________________
1         | walnuts | 16
2         | cashew  | 25
3         | peanuts | 4

Sells (each product kilograms sold):

Day | ProductID | Amt    | Price
__________________________________
1   | 1         | 2      | 15
1   | 2         | 3      | 25
1   | 3         | 1      | 4
2   | 1         | 8      | 16
2   | 2         | 6      | 23
2   | 3         | 25     | 5
3   | 1         | 1      | 16
3   | 2         | 3      | 25
3   | 3         | 12     | 4
```

I put price column in Sells table, because actual sale price can be vary per day.

Once table in this structure, you can do group by to sum up.
Following is MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(Amt * Price) AS total FROM Sells WHERE Day=2 GROUP BY Day
```

If you want to check per day and product with product itself details, you can try following:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Product, SUM(s.Amt * s.Price) AS total 
    FROM Sells AS s
    LEFT JOIN Product AS p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE s.Day=2 GROUP BY s.Day, s.Product
```

**2. If it's not possible to change, then...**

@Kanagaraj Dhanapal 's answer will be yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(prince)
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
         WHEN p.product = "walnuts"
          THEN (s.walnuts * p.price)
         WHEN p.product = "cashew"
          THEN (s.cashew * p.price)
         WHEN p.product = "hazelnut"
          THEN (s.hazelnut * p.price)
         ELSE NULL
           END AS price
    FROM sells s
    JOIN product p 
    WHERE Day = 2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very maintainable but if this is your actual data and for some reason you don't want to just calculate it by hand, then this pattern should work.  (not tested on real data but hopefully close enough to get you going)

```
select
    s.Day,
    p.Product,
    SUM(
        CASE p.Product
            WHEN 'walnuts' THEN p.Price * s.walnuts
            WHEN 'cashew' THEN p.Price * s.cashew
            WHEN 'peanuts' THEN p.Price * s.peanuts
        END
    ) Total
from Product p full join Sells s
group by s.Day, p.Product
```